# Several packages suggested to be autoremoved. Is it safe?

Tags: nvidia, package-management, upgrade, uninstall

Over the past few weeks, I have been "accumulating" a lot of packages to the list of packages I should autoremove because they are "no longer needed".

The problem is, I have a dual boot on my dell xps 15 7590 and I'm always terrified that one major update or autoremove might mess up the booting system and I will be essentially unable to boot either windows or ubuntu (20.04.1 LTS). It was tricky to configure the dual boot and I'm not confident I would be able to fix any serious problems if something important would be deleted. Packages related to my nvidia drivers are being suggested and I'm particularly skeptical about it...

Here is the complete list:

```
duplicity libatomic1:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386
  libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi7:i386 libfprint-2-tod1 libgl1:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386
  libglx0:i386 libllvm10:i386 libllvm9 libllvm9:i386 libnvidia-common-440
  libnvidia-decode-440:i386 libnvidia-decode-450:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-440
  libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-440 libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-450
  libnvidia-ifr1-450:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 librsync2 libsensors5:i386
  libstdc++6:i386 libvulkan1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxnvctrl0 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-headers-5.4.0-53
  linux-headers-5.4.0-53-generic linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-53-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic
  mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-440 nvidia-compute-utils-450
  nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-440 nvidia-utils-450
  python3-bcrypt python3-future python3-lockfile python3-paramiko
  screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450
```

Several of them had been listed as "kept back" packages during routine upgrades with `sudo apt-get upgrade`, so I manually installed them, and now they just appear on that list of packages that are no longer needed and should be removed.

What do you guys think?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The first part are redunant packages for the 32 architecture (I386). They are usually installed together with a 32 bit software, which might you've removed.

The lower part shows the linux headers & kernels not in use anymore. Tehy have been replaced by an update...

Removing the nvidia drivers should not be a problem, if you got newer ones:
`xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440` and `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450` seem to be older packages.

To make sure you*ve got a newer NVIDIA driver check it with `nvidia-smi` (you may have Version -452)

That list looks exhaustive but nothing to worry about...